# PostgreSQL Trigger with two function statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger for 2 distinct functions, with difference only in the condition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seculoxxi()
    RETURNS integer AS $total1$
    declare
        total1 integer;
    BEGIN
       SELECT count(*) into total1 
       FROM edicao
       WHERE ano >= 2000;
       RETURN total1;
    END;
    $total1$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seculoxx()
RETURNS integer AS $total2$
declare
    total2 integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) into total2 
   FROM edicao
   WHERE ano < 2000;
   RETURN total2;
END;
$total2$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The structure of the table is also simple, there are three rows:

1. Code (numeric)
2. Version (character)
3. Year (integer)

How can I create this Trigger?

Comment: I don't understand. You want *what* to be triggered on *what* event?

Comment: Sorry, I need to create a trigger to add the counters in the table. @eurotrash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a total shot in the dark, but assuming the field you want to modify is called "counters," then I think the trigger could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edicao_insert_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  total integer;
BEGIN
  select count (*)
  into total
  from edicao e
  where
    (NEW.ano >= 2000 and e.ano >= 2000) or
    (NEW.ano < 2000 and e.ano < 2000);

  NEW.counter := total;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Then to add the trigger to your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_edicao_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON edicao
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE edicao_insert_trigger()
```

Now, when you do an insert, it should automatically add the value for the "counter" field.

For the record, if you are trying to get a unique id, it would be much better to use a sequence.

```
create sequence edicao_gt_2000;
create sequence edicao_lt_2000;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edicao_insert_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  NEW.counter :=
    case
      when NEW.ano >= 2000 then nextval ('edicao_gt_2000')
      else nextval ('edicao_lt_2000')
    end;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```